# git with https did not work in crontab

Tags: git, cron

I want to do 'git pull' every morning

so I write a shell script run.sh

git --git-dir=/local/git/path/.git pull https://id:pw@bla/bla/bla/bla/bla.git

this script work well when I run

but when i using crontab this script didn't work and print error log like 
"fatal: unable to access 'https://baba@ba/ba.git/': Could not resolve host: baba"

I don't know the reason why,

How can I fix it?

Comment: Did you ran command with the same user than cron does and got a successful result ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Login with Root User using `sudo su`

then try to add same line in crontab using `sudo crontab -e`

And check again, It should be pushed.